# What does an array equal to without the [ ]? c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

for some reason the first number to print out doesn't abide by the for loop in the main function, telling it to range from 0-10; but when

```
void printArray(int augArray[5])
{
    cout << *augArray;         //this line is taken out, the for loop proceeds with normal 
    for (int i = 0; i < 5;)       //outputs, when the first line is kept also the for loop only
    {                                //produces 4 other numbers, just curious to why this is 
        cout << augArray[i] << endl;     //happening, thanks.
        i++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int anArray[5];

    for(int j = 0; j < 5;)
    {
        anArray[j] = rand() % 11;
        j++;
    }

    printArray(anArray);
    cout << anArray;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just tacking the first number to the end of the array address (since you haven't added an `endl`)? Also, why increment the loop counters in the body rather than the `for` line?

Comment: *augArray is exactly the same as augArray[0] - you are getting confused because you are missing an endl in `cout << *augArray;`

Comment: Thanks, yeah it was the endl thing, my mistake next time ill take a closer look... was wondering why they were doubles lol

Answer (score 3):

When an array name is used in an expression without square brackets following it, its value is equal to the pointer to the initial element of the array, i.e. `augArray` in an expression is the same as `&augArray[0]`. Therefore, `*augArray` is the same as `*(&augArray[0])`, which is simply `augArray[0]` (the asterisk and the ampersand cancel each other).

The reason the output looks strange is that you did not put an end-of-line character after you printed `*augArray`. The "weird number" that you see in the output is actually the initial element of the array repeated twice.

Answer (score 0):

It should works just fine except the first output is mixed with the following outputs. To see it more clearly, you should put a newline after you print out the first element:

Change

```
cout << *augArray; // print the first element
```

to

```
cout << *augArray << endl; // print the first element and go to a new-line
```

See it live: http://ideone.com/y16NeP.

---

Sidenote: you can simply put `i++/j++` to the `for`-line, like `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)`.